# MATLAB: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch

Tags: matlab

I do not understnad the reason why MATLAB display error when I type the following lines in the command line.

```
k=2; 

c=[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0];

temp1=[1 0;2 0;1 0;5 0;9 0;5 0;6 0;7 0];

s=c*temp1;

w(2,k)=s
```

**Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.**

```
>> s

s =

     5     0
     9     0
```

where w(2,k) is nothing but a 2x2 matrix and assigned 2x2 matrix and it still display that error. I would like to thank the person who ever out there can help better my understandings on this topic.

Comment: It might help if you could explain a bit more about what you want to achieve. Do you want to fill `w` with the contents of `s`? Also, what is `w`? You didn't define it in your example code.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that `w(2,k)` is a `1x1` matrix and you're trying to put `s`, a `2x2` matrix in it. When you're doing an assignment operation, i.e. `=`, both side of the equals sign have to have the exact same dimensions. If they don't then you get a dimension mismatch error.

if `w` is a `2x2` as you say then `w = s` should work, or `w(2,k) = s(2, k)` should work too. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `w(2,k) = s(2, k)` will only copy one element not the whole matrix

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia of course... That's why I asked what the OP's intentions are